# C++: Solution to this floating point error problem?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

This is an example of my code:

```
float a = 0.f;
float b = 5.f;
float increment = 0.1f;
while(a != b)
    a+=increment;
```

This will result in an infinite loop. Is there any solutions to it, or the only way to solve this is to set a tolerance?

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: In general, yes a tolerance could help `while (std::fabs(b-a) < 1.0e-6)` or whatever

Comment: In general, by whatever means, always use integer as the looping condition.  If you know you must loop `n` times, then loop `n` times, then figure out any floating point within the loop.

Comment: In general, loop termination conditions that depend on incrementing numeric values ought to be written with `<` rather than `!=`. That avoids this kind of problem. `while (a < b)` is not an infinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid using floating-point calculation when possible. In this case you can treat with the numbers as integer by multiplying them by 10 and dividing by 10 in the end.

```
float a, b, increment;
int a_i = 0;
int b_i = 50;
int increment_i = 1;
while(a_i != b_i)
    a_i+=increment_i;
a = a_i / 10.f,
b = b_i / 10.f;
increment = increment_i / 10.f;
```